# amchart regular numeric scale on category axis in x-axis

Tags: regex, numeric, amcharts

I'm new to programming and now I want to give custom label on categoryAxies in line chart.

But that label should be regular(like 0,50,100,150).

This is my format of data.

```
59.0472,0.0318 
69.071,0.0271 
72.0913,0.0271 
81.0674,0.0334 
81.0734,0.0382 
83.0596,0.0717 
83.0894,0.0605 
85.0817,0.035 
85.1053,0.0287 
86.0675,0.0318 
87.1001,0.0287 
90.6657,0.0382
```

I want x-axis as `0, 50 , 60,` etc.

Also i have mentioned the category axis code in below

```
var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis; 
categoryAxis.parseDates = false; 
categoryAxis.autoGridCount =false;

categoryAxis.dashLength = 1; 
categoryAxis.gridCount = 6; 
categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0.15; 
categoryAxis.minorGridEnabled = true; 
categoryAxis.axisColor = "#DADADA";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you X axis should be numeric, than I would recommend you using XY chart instead of Serial, for example: http://www.amcharts.com/javascript-charts/scatter/